# How to toggle the <div> using data(data-class) attribute

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, custom-data-attribute

am very new to j query, I want to toggle the div using data(data-class) attribute rather than using separate class name for div .. please help me ... thanks in advance

```
<div id="click" class="toggle">Toggle </div>
<div id="slide" data-class="slide" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle">Toggle </div>
<div data-class="slide1" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle">Toggle </div>
<div data-class="slide2" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
        var tog = $(this).("data-class");
    $("."+tog).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attr()` or `data()` to get the value of your data attribute, so you can use:

```
var tog = $(this).attr("data-class");
```

or:

```
var tog = $(this).data("class");
```

instead of:

```
var tog = $(this).("data-class");
```

---

After going through your HTML markup, you need to change your HTML to:

```
<div id="click" data-class="slide" class="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide" data-class="slide" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
<div data-class="slide1" class="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="slide1" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
<div data-class="slide2" class="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="slide2" style="display:none;">
    <p>name 1</p>
    <p>name 2</p>
    <p>name 3</p>
</div>
```

You need to add `data-class` attribute on the `.toggle` div, not for the hidden div. Also you need to add `class` for your hidden div respectively.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9S9Y4/)**

Comment: agh, im too slow. lol :) do you know why .prop doesnt work btw?

Comment: @Felix Hey great dude , it is working , But i have doubt that how the div which having data attribute is toggling another .. where is the connection point, can u explain

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.attr('data-class')` or `.data('class');`..

here is your updated code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
         $(this).children(':first').slideToggle( "fast", function() {
             // Animation complete.
         });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , i just copy and paste your updated code but it is not working .

Comment: How bout that? @Error just slidetoggling the child as the htmlmarkup is the same for all.

Comment: Hey JF just now i seen the result, its not working even add your updated code